# How can I improve my jQuery show/hide implementation?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm using the following to show and hide divs. It works but I can't help thinking it could be more efficient. In the simplified example I'm showing 3 countries, but my code will need to handle a couple of dozen. I'm very new to jQuery. Is there a way to just say "show *any* country when clicked, and hide the rest"?

The HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <span id="France">France</span>
    <span id="Canada">Canada</span>
    <span id="Portugal">Portugal</span>
</div>

<!-- show div based on which span is clicked; hide the rest -->
<div class="content">
    <div class="France all">...</div>
    <div class="Canada all">...</div>
    <div class="Portugal all">...</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#France").click(function(){
            $(".all").hide();
            $(".France").show();                
    }); 

    $("#Canada").click(function(){
            $(".all").hide();
            $(".Canada").show("");
            }); 

    $("#Portugal").click(function(){
            $(".all").hide();
            $(".Portugal").show("");        
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this :

```
$('.nav span').click(function(){
    $('.all').hide();
    $('.'+this.id).show();
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/qVEAR/)

Answer (score 1):

You can take away the class `all` and use `.siblings().hide()`

```
$('.nav span').click(function(){
    $('.'+this.id).show("").siblings().hide("");
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.nav span').on('click', function() {
    $('.content > div').eq($(this).index()).toggle().siblings().hide();
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mHaN/)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of what's showing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $current,
        $contents = $('.content .all').hide();

    $('.nav span').click(function() {
        if ($current) {
            $current.hide();
        }
        $current = $contents.filter('.' + this.id).show();
    });
}); ​
```